# Group chat function XMPP on Android

Tags: android

Could you give me any tutorial about group chat using XMPP?

i try what was written in documentation but it is failed.

My function

```
public void invitegroupchat() throws XMPPException{
        MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(mConnection, "roomname@servername");
        muc.create("admin@servername");
        Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
        for (Iterator fields = form.getFields();fields.hasNext();){
          FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
            if(!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable()!= null){
                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }               
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
        muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
        muc.join("admin@servername");

   }
```

That function call when button is click. I debug it error when call muc.create... the exception is remote server not found (404) anyone could help me to solve this?